# How JWT parse with claims validity and error work?

Tags: go, jwt

I'm creating access, refresh token logic and I want to check if access token is valid (not edited) even if it is expired. Go returns error and makes token invalid, if token is expired. So I check if the given error match with ErrTokenExpired.

Can I be 100% sure that if the token is not valid then the err will not be nil, so I can delete `if !tkn.Valid{...`?

Is it generally a good approach or edited tokens can pass my veryfication?

```
func VerifyJWT(jwtString, secret string) (*jwt.Token, *Claims, error) {
    claims := &Claims{}
    tkn, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(jwtString, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        return []byte(os.Getenv(secret)), nil
    })
    return tkn, claims, err
}
```

```
    _, accClaims, err1 := VerifyJWT(req.Access, "ACCESS_SECRET")
    if err1 != nil && err1.Error()[:16] != jwt.ErrTokenExpired.Error()[:16] {
        WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, APIError{Error: "invalid token access" + err1.Error()})
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your code have two point, jwt token is safe:

1- choose good algorithm
2- create random secret key

If token changed or timeout, this two choose can help you and `VerifyJWT` return error!

Note: always you need check errors, and return good response to client.

---

Note (improve your code): for check one error is ErrTokenExpired, use `errors` pkg.

Your example:

```golang
// import "errors"


_, accClaims, err := VerifyJWT(req.Access, "ACCESS_SECRET")
if errors.Is(err, jwt.ErrTokenExpired) {
        // continue progress
}

if err != nil {
    WriteJSON(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, APIError{Error: err.Error()})
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to return if the token is expired so if the user is not active for the access token lifespan, he will not log in to the system again and just use refresh token. I want the expiration error to be ignored.

Comment: Not need ignore it !
Return error to client, client chooses send refresh token or not!
If want dont return error, in first error check add your action! ( i change code )